# Bulk enable product stock management in Woocommerce

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, woocommerce

I have a WooCommerce shop with around 12,000 products and only about 10% have stock management enabled. I need to bulk enable stock management on all products.

Does anyone have any ideas for the best way to accomplish this?

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**To bulk enabling stock management for all products. There are 2 ways:**

1. PHP: Using the following code will update the database with a very light SQL query:

   function bulk_enable_product_stock_management(){
   // Only for administrator user role
   if( ! current_user_can( 'administrator' ) ) return;

   ```
    global $wpdb;

    $wpdb->query( "
        UPDATE {$wpdb->prefix}postmeta
        SET meta_value = 'yes'
        WHERE meta_key = '_manage_stock'
    " );
   ```

   }

   bulk_enable_product_stock_management();

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

> **USAGE** Once saved, to run the code, browse any page of your web site as an administrator. Then remove this code.

---

2. MySQL/SQL: With a direct SQL query using PhpMyAdmin:

   UPDATE wp_postmeta
   SET meta_value = 'yes'
   WHERE meta_key = '_manage_stock'

Both ways will bulk enable product stock management